# Can より be used differently than saying "b more x than a"?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-より

I could not find any examples of this usage, but what I'm basically asking is whether or not this is possible:

> 怒るより悲しいですよ
>
> Rather than being mad, I am sad

Is this a legitimate way of using より?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a legitimate way of using より, but not a legitimate way of using 怒る ;) (If I understand you correctly, that is.)

For 怒る, you want to express a state, which you should do with the ~ている form. That is,

> 怒ってるより悲しいんです

(Inserting the explanatory ん makes it sound a little better...)

より works best though, if you use two constructions, which are the same, e.g.

> 怒ってるより、苦しんでいます

Other variations on the same theme:

> 怒ってるというより、悲しいんですよ
>   怒ってるんじゃなくて、悲しいんですよ
>   怒ってるというか、悲しいんですよ

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to put in ってる
Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I find that [というより](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A&ref=sa) is also a good way to say it.